# fullpage.js - how to set up 2 different sets of slide - one that moves and one that does not

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, slider, fullpage.js

I am using https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js for full page scroll and was wondering if someone can help me...

There is a function for auto-play of slides (side-to-side) but I am not savvy enough to understand how to make this happen for one section and not for second section.

In the below example: http://jsfiddle.net/2dhkR/106/  I would like to have section 2 - be able to do the auto-slideshow mode and have section 3 NOT have the auto slideshow mode.

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">Section 1</div>
    <div class="section">Section 2
        <div class="slide">Slide 2.1 - should autoslide</div>
        <div class="slide">Slide 2.2 - should autoslide</div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">Section 3
        <div class="slide">Slide 3.1 - should not autoslide</div>
        <div class="slide">Slide 3.2 - should not autoslide</div>
    </div>
</div>


$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        'slidesColor': ['#AAA', '#FFB', '#0BD'],
        'scrollingSpeed': 700,
        'anchors': ['first', 'second', 'third', 'forth'],
        'controlArrowColor': '#000',
            'navigation': true,
            'navigationPosition': 'right',
            'navigationColor': '#000',
            'navigationTooltips': [],
            'slidesNavigation': true,
            'slidesNavPosition': 'bottom',
            'controlArrowColor': '#000',
            'loopBottom': true,
            'loopTop': false,
            'loopHorizontal': true,
            'autoScrolling': true,
            'scrollOverflow': true,

        afterRender: function () {
            setInterval(function () {
                $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideRight();
            }, 2000);
        }
    });
});
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the answer in the fullpage.js forum where you posted the same one:
https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/431#issuecomment-42404270

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.fn.fullpage({
        slidesColor: ['#1bbc9b', '#4BBFC3', '#7BAABE', 'whitesmoke', '#ccddff'],
        loopBottom: true,
        afterRender: function(){
            idInterval = setInterval(function(){
                    $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideRight();
            }, 2500);
        },
        afterSlideLoad: function(anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex){
            if(index == 1 && slideIndex == 1){
                clearInterval(idInterval);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/2dhkR/96/)

Comment: may be my english is bad - and my question is not making sense. you link remove section 3 altogether..  I want section 2 to have auto-slide-mover action - but not section 3.

Comment: It was just an example of how to use the functions `clearInterval` with `setInterval` and the callbacks provided by the plugin. Please, try to understand how it works and apply it to your code...

Comment: answer make may day. just as Alvaro said check documentation ( change afterSlideLoad to `afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
            if(index == 2){ //when get to section 2 do ths
               idInterval = setInterval(function(){
                    $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideRight();
               }, 2500);
            } 
            if(index == 3){ //when get to section 3 do this
                clearInterval(idInterval);
            }